# Storm - fields grouping for same machine?

Tags: apache-storm

1. I use `fields grouping` with storm.
2. The problem is that because I have multiple machines and multiple bolts (obviously) then the `tuple` moves in between the machine and I suspect this reduces my performance drastically.
3. Is it possible for a specific field grouping outcome to be specific to a specific machine?
4. Or in more details for field grouping `account1` be sticky with all bolts to `machine1` for `account2` `machine3` for `account3` be sticky for all bolts to `machine1` and so on for each `account` to have all its bolts running in a specific single machine?
5. Note that once the first `bolt` processes the event it emits `accountid` in its output tuple all further `bolts` from that point and on have `accountid` meaning I would want to do `field grouping` from that point and on on `accountid` for further `bolts` in the `topology`. (added for clarification after seeing first answer)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368224/is-there-a-way-to-apply-multiple-groupings-in-storm/36374837?noredirect=1#comment60465924_36374837 also discusses the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can localOrShuffleGrouping help?
https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/a4f9f8bc5b4ca85de487a0a868e519ddcb94e852/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/topology/TopologyBuilder.java#L360

Comment: is it deterministic i mean for a certain key `account1` would it be possible that on one tuple it will reach `local bolt` and on another reach a `remote bolt` or if it sent something to `local bolt` it will keep on with it and for `account2` if sent to `remote bolt` it would continue sending it to that same `remote bolt` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have 3 producers P1,P2,P3 and three consumers C1,C2,C3 and 3 machines each hosting a single Producer-Consumer-Pair, ie, P1-C1. Furthermore, assume you have 3 distinct key values `a,b,c`. Furthermore, assume that C1 processes all tuples with key `a`.

In general, tuples with key `a` can be emitted by all three producers. Furthermore, P1, can also emit tuples with key `b` or `c`. Thus, you cannot limit the data transfer to local machines using fields-grouping all you need to re-partition all data.

**Extension**

If you have additional bolts B1 to B3 that consumes data from C1 to C3 and those use the same fields-grouping key as C1 to C3 (ie, Bx could exploit the already given partitioning from Cx), you would need to ensure that B1 to B3 are co-located on the same machine as C1 to C3 and avoid a re-partitioning. Co-location can be achieved by providing a custom scheduler to Storm. See here for an example: https://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/

However, you **cannot** use field-grouping to connect B1->C1 etc. because fields-grouping is agnostic to operator co-location and the already given partitioned data (it would just re-partition that data again). Instead, you would need to use direct- or custom-grouping to ensure that all data from B1 is sent to C1 etc.

Comment: What I thought of is having each and every of the `(Px,Cx)` pair on all of the machines and in my case as soon as `C1` emits its results it has the `accountid` in this result so that I can from now and on do `fields grouping` on this `accountid` all further producers and consumers in this topology from that point and on would all have an `accountid` in their outputs so in that case I do have an `accountid` emitted in all outputs but the first output and was planning to have all Px,Cx on all hosts.  any chance such a thing would be possible with `storm` implementation?

Comment: I cannot follow... What do you mean by "having each and every of the `(Px,Cx)` pair on all of the machines" ? I extended my answer (hope this covers the second part of your question -- if I understand you correctly)