# Is there a way to apply multiple groupings in storm?

Tags: apache-storm, elasticsearch-hadoop

I want to apply "Fields grouping" as well as "Local or shuffle grouping" to my topology such that each spout sends data to local bolts only but also uses a field in my document to decide what local-bolts it should go to.

So if there were two worker processes each with 1 Kafka-Spout and 2 elastic-search-bolts, local-or-shuffle grouping gives me the following:

```
Each KS ---> Two local ES-Bolts
```

fields-grouping gives me the following:

```
Each KS ---> Possibly all 4 ES-bolts, depending on the value of the field
```

But I want to have the following:

```
Each KS ---> Two local ES-bolts only, but distribution among these
             local bolts should depend on the value of the field
```

where:

KS = Kafka-Spout

ES = Elastic-Search

I want to do this so that I can group all the documents for a single shard together in ES-bolt. This way the batch sent by an ES-bolt will not be split further by the ES-server as all those document's destination shard will be the same (I plan to add field *destination_shard* to the documents for field-level grouping and destination_shard will be calculated as *Murmurm3.hash(ID)%numShards*).

And then I do not want any inter-process communication, hence the need for "local or shuffle grouping"

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and Yes.

There is no grouping value that does what you want, but you can implement that grouping yourself using:

1) Directed streams, in which you specify the task id of the bolt instance to process the tuple (rather than let Storm figure it out)

2) The topology context passed to each bolt and spout on startup.  That object can tell you which tasks are running on the current worker (using `getThisWorkerTasks()`) and what bolts have which tasks (`getComponentTasks()`)

3) Your own partitioning logic as you've described above and which makes use of the info in (2)  above to specify the specific target task for each of your bolt's outbound tuples.

Comment: The biggest problem with this approach is the emitDirect() method that need to be used with directed streams. I am using KafkaSpout and have no control over its emit methods. 

Also, do you think the above logic can be expressed easily with Flux configuration?

Comment: The problem is really with the use of KafkaSpout, which as you're seeing is quite inflexible.  Try sending the tuples from KafkaSpout to your own bolt and put the above direct stream logic in that bolt.